# Can we have content text directly in <div>?

Tags: html

can we have content text directly in `<div>text content</div>` or it should be like `<div><p>text content</p></div>`? according to web standards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have character data directly inside a div element. If (and only if) that character data is a paragraph, then it should also be marked up as a paragraph (as per your second example). If you only have one paragraph of content inside the div, then you should usually avoid having the div element as it serves no purpose.

Comment: I disagree that the `div` element would always serve no purpose. If you have reusable OOCSS-type styles, or if the text could expand to more than one paragraph in the future (and those paragraphs need to function as a block together), then wrapping it in a `div` could be perfectly reasonable. You don't know the *purpose* of the html, so how can you legitimately dictate the structure! Consider the case of the nested `div` and `p`--if you combine them and their styling into a single `p`, then you have to split it back out when the content changes to two paragraphs. That shows fragility.

Comment: It would be great to have an explicit discussion of the accessibility implications here, if any.

Answer (score 4):

There's a two questions implied here, **can** and **should**. **can** is straight-forward, **should** is not.

> So, **Can** you nest content text directly into a div?

The [current active spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) states `The div element has no special meaning **at all**`. So, **yes** there is no reason why you cannot nest text directly into a div, **but** that text *has no special meaning*.

> **Should** you nest content text directly into a div?

**No**, not really. There is one fundamental problem with putting text into an element that *has no special meaning*. What does that text mean? Is it a title or a simple block of text, etc. For most people this isn't an issue. If you're using a screen reader it is. The screen reader needs more information to understand the context of the text. This is why the [HTML spec on `div`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) now includes the following text:

> **Note** Authors are strongly encouraged to view the div element as an element of last resort, for when no other element is suitable. Use of
> more appropriate elements instead of the div element leads to better
> accessibility for readers and easier maintainability for authors.

so ideally all your text should be nested into a HTML element that represents it's context, e.g. `<p>`, `<h1>`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* have it directly in a [`div`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DIV.asp). The `div` is often used to group block-elements to format them with styles, but normal, unmarkedup text in a `div` is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can directly add content text into a div tag, although using p tags would be preferable in most circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Screen readers seem to handle `<div>phrasing content</div>` and `<div><p>phrasing content</p></div>`

differently in some circumstances.

It seems that the rules for elements that can contain flow content and elements that can contain phrasing content are different.

Answer (score 0):

The standards are not so well defined.  I would choose your second example, because it is more structurally sound, and therefore more semantic.